# Calculadora Bhaskara Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, estou começando a programar e minha dúvida é a seguinte:
1) Criei essa página HTML para calcular uma fórmula simples de bhaskara:

```js
let valorA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('#a').value);
var numA = valorA;

let valorB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('#b').value);
var numB = valorB;

let valorC = parseFloat(document.getElementById('#c').value);
var numC = valorC;

function calc() {
    var delta=((Math.pow(numB,2))-((4*numA)*numC));
    var raiz=Math.sqrt(delta);
    var base=2*numA;
    // validar a, b, c
    if (delta < 0)
    {
        alert("Nao tem resposta")
    }
    else if(delta === 0)
    {
    var deltaX = (numB*(-1)) / base;
    document.getElementById('x1').innerHTML = deltaX;
    }
    else
    {
        var x1=(-numB+raiz)/base;
        var x2=(-numB-raiz)/base;
        document.getElementById('delta').innerHTML = delta;
        document.getElementById('x1').innerHTML = x1;
        document.getElementById('x2').innerHTML = x2;
    }
}

let button = document.querySelector('#buttonC');
button.addEventListener('click', calc);
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Calculadora de Bhaskara</p>
<form action="" method="post" name="bhaskara">
    <label id="label-a">A: </label>
    <input id="a" type="number" value="1">

    <label id="label-b">B: </label>
    <input id="b" type="number" value="1">

    <label id="label-c">C: </label>
    <input id="c" type="number" value="1">
    <br>
    <button id="buttonC">Calcular</button>
    <br>
</form>
<section>
    <label id="label-delta">DELTA: </label>
    <input id="delta" type="text" disabled>

    <label id="label-x1">X1: </label>
    <input id="x1" type="text" disabled>

    <label id="label-c">X2: </label>
    <input id="x2" type="text" disabled>
</section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Queria digitar os valores de A/B e C, apertar o botão calcular e devolver para os input's desabilitados.

Pode parecer bobo, mas estou a 4 horas tentando fazer funcionar e nada.

Comment: A atribuição de valorA, valorB e valorC não deveria estar dentro da função calc?

Comment: Também acho que deveria, pra não criar variáveis de escopo global

Answer (score 2):

Utilize

> document.getElementById('x2').**value**= x2;

e faça as alterações na lógica para que desabilite os botões utilizando:

> document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;

como descreve o exemplo [Button disabled Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp)

```
<section>
    <label id="label-delta">DELTA: </label>
    <input class='calc-button' id="delta" type="text">

    <label id="label-x1">X1: </label>
    <input class='calc-button' id="x1" type="text">

    <label id="label-c">X2: </label>
    <input class='calc-button' id="x2" type="text">
</section>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".calc-button")

    //JS puro
    for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }

</script>
```

ES6

```
buttons.map(button => button.disabled = true)
```

jQuery

```
 $('.calc-button').each(function(){
     this.prop('disabled', true);
 })
```

JQuery + ES6

```
 $('.calc-button').each(() => this.prop('disabled', true))
```

> Não esqueça de executar esse método **após "setar" os valores dos**
>   **inputs**

Comment: Desculpe, mas continuo sem entender.

Comment: Coloquei códigos pra facilitar